# Android AsyncTask: when it starts?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm doing background things using `AsyncTask`. I have been knowing that operations are just executed **parallelly** in `AsyncTask` however don't know about when it starts.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lec_refer_room);

        String subCode = null;

        try{
            System.out.println(subCode);
        }catch(Exception e){
            finish();
        }

        new GetRefer(subCode, page).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        // this is AsyncTask
    }
```

I tried to finish activity when string `subCode` is null. However above code occurs exception in `GetRefer().executeOnExecutor()`

Does AsyncTask starts along with main thread?
Then how can I use try-catch with AsycTask?

Comment: You want to `finish()` acivity on a `Thread`?

Comment: What do you mean `Thread`?

Comment: See my answer let me know if it was you was trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a sample to show to you how `AsyncTask` works hope it what you was asking for

```
 public class TaskTest extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {


    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        Boolean StringNull = false;
         String subCode = params[0];

         if (subCode == null){
            StringNull = true;
         }

        return StringNull;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (!result) {
             System.out.println(subCode);
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

To execute it you have to do as follows :

```
TastkTest tasktest = new TaskTest();
tasktest.execute(subCode);
```

### Edit (Final Code)

Inside of your `onCreate()`

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lec_refer_room);

    String subCode = null;
    TastkTest tasktest = new TaskTest();
    tasktest.execute(subCode);

}
```

The `InnerClass` still the same.

### Edit2

If you want to put it on `onCreate()` do as follows...

```
String subCode = null;

    if(subCode==null){
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean `StringNull = true` instead of `subCode = null`?

Comment: Your answer seems correct but can't `finish()` done in `onCreate()`?

Comment: Just call this method on `onCreate()`

Comment: Thanks but just curious, is it impossible to call `finish()` in `onCreate()` like my question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87891/discussion-between-skizo-and-user3858358).

Answer (score 0):

You could call `finish ()` in your `onCreate()` but it's not something you probably want to do as the user would have no idea why the `Activity` didn't start.

This article will help explain the way `AsyncTask` works: http://hiqes.com/androids-asynctask-explained/